# Dialog not rendering page on Iframe using external service

Tags: jquery, iframe

In the code given below, jQuery dialog not loading jsp coming as response in the provided Uploadurl. Although the same is working fine with MAC OS and Chrome browser but not working with Windows Machine Chrome browser. This problem is for first time load only. When one cancel the dialog and try to open again functionality is working fine.

I have tried putting `async: true` in the dialog itself. Being a beginner in jQuery.

```
$dialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Submit File',
        width: 700,
        buttons: [
            {
                'text': 'Cancel',
                'class': 'btn-cancel',
                'click': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            {
                'text': 'Upload',
                'class': 'btn-upload',
                'click': function(){
                    $(this).find('iframe')[0].contentWindow.submitFileUpload($row);
                }
            }
        ],
        open: function(){
            $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', uploadUrl);
        }
    });
```

First time load on window machine should work fine.

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: There is no error but a warning for deprecated jquery lib - "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Comment: That could be the reason why chrome is not loading it for the first time. try putting  `$(this).find('iframe').attr('src', uploadUrl);` inside a `setTimeout` with `0` as interval

Comment: I have tried putting the statement in setTimeout but that could not work. Actually the call to service doesn't seems to be going at first load. I can check it in networks while debugging.

Comment: I think it is due to `window.load` waiting for iframe source to be loaded and getting stuck so chrome decides to not make the call. Do one thing, Remove the iframe itself from the view. After open, instead of setting the source to the iframe, create the iframe at run time with desired url and append to the dialog body.

Comment: Thanks Cerlin,  settimeout think worked for me. Earlier, i was putting that incorrectly. Could you please help me understanding why that worked?

Comment: SetTimeout with `0` as delay moves the execution to the end of execution stack instead of executing immediately. So technically you are just reordering the execution to execute the html rendering logic first and then updating its src.